# Custom jQuery Recaptcha

Tags: php, jquery, forms, post, recaptcha

Does anyone know how to do a custom jQuery ReCaptcha? I have viewed related posts on Stack Overflow, but none related to forms with customer themes / styling. I am using a HTML form that will be submitted via JQuery AJAX, and the $POST will be submitted to an PHP page that will echo a code (an integer) and based of of that response (1, 2, 9, 7,..), a notification will appear. How do I go about implementing this with custom styling and custom theme?

Answer (score 0):

You should add some JavaScript code and CSS styling to your site.

Check this: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/customization

Good luck!